# www-data to call program that reads file

Tags: c, apache, ubuntu, permissions, chmod

On an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS server, a web page calls a PHP script which runs an executable. This works fine, even on executables belonging to root (these executables have access mode 0755).

However, when the web page calls a PHP script to run an executable, and that executable tries to open a file for reading, then the program runs but cannot open the file.

What needs to change so that Apache (www-data) can run an executable (which I've written in C) that opens a file for reading?

Let's call the executable ExecutableFile. The file to be opened for reading can be called FileToRead, and it lives in a directory named DirectoryContainingFileToRead. This directory is in the same directory as ExecutableFile.

ExecutableFile is given FileToRead in the command line. It knows to look in DirectoryContainingFileToRead. If it finds it, it computes results with reference to this file. If it cannot find it, the program computes default results.

PHP calls executables using its exec() function, like so:

```
$data = exec('./ExecutableFile FileToRead OtherArgument 2>&1');
```

Here's what I've already tried, to no avail:

1. Changing ownership of the files involved.
   ExecutableFile has mode 755.
   DirectoryContainingFileToRead has mode 755.
   FileToRead has mode 644.

   ```
   chown www-data.www-data ExecutableFile
   chown www-data.www-data DirectoryContainingFileToRead
   chown www-data.www-data DirectoryContainingFileToRead/FileToRead
   ```

This produces no change. (As noted above, other executables which do not attempt to open files will still run when called by www-data, even though they belong to root.root. These have read and execute permissions enabled for everybody.)

2. The same as above, but leaving the group as root:

   ```
   chown www-data.root ExecutableFile
   chown www-data.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead
   chown www-data.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead/FileToRead
   ```

This produces no change. The default results are returned.

3. Leaving all files the property of root and changing the sticky bit on ExecutableFile only:

   ```
   chown root.root ExecutableFile
   chown root.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead
   chown root.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead/FileToRead
   chmod +s ExecutableFile
   ```

This produces no change: the executable will still run, though it does not open the file.

4. Changing the sticky bit on all files involved:

   ```
   chown root.root ExecutableFile
   chown root.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead
   chown root.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead/FileToRead
   chmod +s ExecutableFileName
   chmod +s DirectoryContainingFileToRead
   chmod +s DirectoryContainingFileToRead/FileToRead
   ```

This produces no change: program runs but does not open the file. Default results are returned.

5. Changing the owner for all files to www-data and setting the sticky bit for ExecutableFile only:

   ```
   chown www-data.root ExecutableFile
   chown www-data.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead
   chown www-data.root DirectoryContainingFileToRead/FileToRead
   chmod +s ExecutableFileName
   ```

Same default results.

6. Recompiling the program to use setuid(0); before attempting to open the file:

   ```
   FILE* fp;
   char fpath[64];
   int currentUID = getuid();                      //  Save given UID
   sprintf(fpath, "./DirectoryContainingFileToRead/%s", FileToRead);
   if(setuid(0) < 0)                               //  Briefly become root
     {
       printf("Unable to become root\n");
       exit(1);
     }
   fp = fopen(fpath, "rb");
   if(fp == NULL)
     {
       //  Proceed without use of the file
     }
   else
     {
       //  Make use of the file
       fclose(fp);
     }
   if(setuid(currentUID) < 0)                      //  Resume being yourself
     {
       printf("Unable to resume given identity\n");
       exit(1);
     }
   ```

This exits when attempted to become root. ExecutableFile has 755. DirectoryContainingFileToRead has 755. FileToRead has 644.

7. The same as attempt 6, but also setting the sticky bit on the executable as in attempt.

   ```
   chmod +s ExecutableFile
   ```

This will at least run without exiting, but the results indicate that it does not open the file.

8. The same as attempt 6, but setting the sticky bit on all files involved:

   ```
   chmod +s ExecutableFileName
   chmod +s DirectoryContainingFileToRead
   chmod +s DirectoryContainingFileToRead/FileToRead
   ```

Again, this will at least run, but the results indicate that the program is not allowed access to the file.

I'm ripping my hair out over this. I've been researching this problem all day. I've consulted other discussions on StackOverflow, Wikipedia, Tanenbaum & Bos' *Modern Operating Systems*. All these sources suggest that permissions are at stake, but none of my attempted solutions works in practice. Any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man. A stupid oversight was behind this:

Everything works fine if I use the absolute path for the file to be read, like this:

```
sprintf(fpath, "/var/long/path/DirectoryContainingFileToRead/%s", FileToRead);
```

No sticky bits needed. I didn't even need to `chown` anything: ExecutableFile, DirectoryContainingFileToRead, and FileToRead all belong to root. Just make sure that the executable and the directory have read and execute by anybody enabled. The file to read should be readable by anybody.

To be clear, PHP calls like this:

```
$data = exec('../../ExecutableFile FileToRead OtherArgument 2>&1');
```

I had omitted the relative path used by PHP in my original post, thinking it was not relevant. In fact, it is necessary to a complete understanding of this problem.

Relative path in the PHP command. Absolute path in the C code.

So much wasted aggravation...